# "The last I saw of that" as a replacement for "the last time I saw that"

Tags: phrase-choice

> The last time I saw that show, X died. Fell down the elevator shaft.
>
> The last I saw of that show, X died. Fell down the elevator shaft.
>
> ---
>
> The last time I saw him, it was 11 years ago.
>
> The last I saw of him was 11 years ago.

Are the pairs of sentences equivalent? Can "the last I saw of that" replace "the last time I saw that" in a sentence?

Answer (score 4):

"The last I saw of X" usually has an implication that X has disappeared, not just that you in particular have stopped looking at X.

> The last time I saw Bob, he was in the conference room.
>
> The last I saw of Bob, he was on a plane headed to Antarctica.

I would not use it as a general replacement.

Comment: +1 particularly for the final sentence. I can't quite put my finger on why *The last I saw of Westworld, Bernard killed Theresa* doesn't work. I *think* it might be because the construction *the last I saw of X [, blah blah]* actually *requires* that X be mentioned again somewhere within *[blah blah]* (unless *[blah blah]* is a "copula", as in *The last I saw of him **was** at the New Year party*) but that's a wild guess. Any thoughts?

Comment: +1.  @FumbleFIngers: *The last I saw of him was when...* is fairly well attested. I don't much like it, but there you have it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  It might be because the "the last I saw of ..." implies the thing or person has gone missing, and a TV show can't do that?

Comment: @TRomano: Glancing through written instances of [The last I saw of him was when](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22The+last+I+saw+of+him+was+when%22), it looks like in most of them the very next word is ***he***. Those that *don't* refer back to "him" in one way or another mostly seem to follow ***when*** with some phrase X that identifies "a period of time" being equated with the aforementioned "last time", which is what I meant by *unless [blah blah] is a "copula"*. I don't have *quite* so much of a problem with *The last I saw of Westworld **was when** Bernard killed Theresa*.